# How to uninstall mySQL when "rm /usr/local/mysql" returns permissions error?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I have been having problems logging into MySQL through phpMyAdmin so I decided to uninstall both on my computer. To my surprise, I do not even have the permissions to *uninstall* MySQL.

I tried to uninstall MySQL using the command "sudo rm /usr/local/mysql" and the terminal returned that I did not have permission.

I looked up a StackOverflow question about not having access to /usr/local and a reply asked the user to do sudo $chown, which my terminal said I did not have permission to do.

I did have permission to do **ls -la /usr/local**, and this is what the terminal returned:

```
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x  16 root  wheel   512 Jun  6 22:32 .
    drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   288 Mar 27  2018 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 x     wheel     0 Feb 19 23:21 
    .com.apple.installer.keep
    drwxrwxr-x   4 x     admin   128 Jun  7  2018 Cellar
    drwxrwxr-x  17 x     admin   544 May 22  2018 Homebrew
    drwxrwxr-x  61 x     admin  1952 Jun  7  2018 bin
    drwxrwxr-x   3 x     admin    96 May 22  2018 etc
    drwxr-xr-x  10 x     wheel   320 May 22  2018 git
    drwxrwxr-x   3 x     admin    96 May 22  2018 lib
    drwxrwxr-x   5 x     wheel   160 May 22  2018 libexec
    lrwxr-xr-x   1 x     wheel    30 Jun  6 22:32 mysql -> mysql-5.7.26- 
    macos10.14-x86_64
    drwxr-xr-x  13 x     wheel   416 Jun  6 22:32 mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14- 
    x86_64
    drwxrwxr-x   4 x     admin   128 Jun  7  2018 opt
    drwxr-xr-x   3 x     wheel    96 May 22  2018 remotedesktop
    drwxrwxr-x   5 x     admin   160 May 22  2018 share
    drwxrwxr-x   3 x     admin    96 May 22  2018 var
```

I am shocked about the "remotedesktop" line, but I hope it is innocent considering it shows up the same day as Homebrew. Please help me understand these results and what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a directory with `rm` unless you use the recursive flag (`-r`). You should get an "is a directory" error, not a permissions error. You'll probably want to include the "force" flag (`-f`) to avoid having to confirm each deletion.

That's also a symlink so you need to remove the specific instance of it, or adapt your command to remove anything MySQL-ish using a wildcard:

```
 rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
```

> As always, **pay extremely close attention to what you're doing when using recursive deletes and `sudo`**. A single space in the wrong place can utterly ruin your day. **Triple check** before executing these commands.